# How to add a datepicker to a custom page in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, datepicker

I have a WordPress site and created a custom page (due to connecting with a separate database).  On this custom page I am creating an advanced search form. On the search form I have a start date datepicker and an end date datepicker.

For some apparent reason, I cannot seem to get the jQuery datepickers or even the HTML datepicker to work for my custom form coding.  I found a JavaScript one that works somewhat, but the problem is when you pick a date, it will put the next day date in the text box.  And the other problem is the calendar looks bad design wise.

Now there are other aspects on this form, but they are all working correctly.  And I am using PHP and PostgreSQL to get the research information.  I have the headers and form code below.  And put a link to the JavaScript code for the date picker.

How can I make the pick a date and the CSS better?

Headers:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/VCSWeb/wp-content/themes/i-excel-child/css/datepicker.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/VCSWeb/wp-content/themes/i-excel-child/js/datepicker.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/VCSWeb/wp-content/themes/i-excel-child/js/timepicker.js"></script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd");
$( "#format" ).change(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
});
});
</script>
```

Form:

```
<form role="search" name="remarks_lookup" method="post" class="search-form" action="#samepage" >
<div style="padding-left:10px; width:25%; float:left; margin-top:-20px; ">                              
<label style="font-size:12px;">Start Date: <br />    
<input style="height:22px;" id="start_dt" name="start_date" class='datepicker boxstyle' size='20' placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" value="" title='YYYY-MM-DD'  />
</label>
</div>                                          
<div style="padding-left:10px; width:75%; float:left; margin-top:-20px;">
<label>End Date: <br />
<input style="height:22px;" id="end_dt" name="end_date"class='datepicker boxstyle' placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD" size='20' value="" title='YYYY-MM-DD' />    
</label>    
</div>
</form>
```

DatePicker Js:

```
// Converts a date into '2016-04-29' format
function getDateString(dt) {
  return  dt.getFullYear() + '-' + 
    ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12'][dt.getMonth()] + 
    '-' + ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20','21','22','23','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'][dt.getDate()];
}

// Converts a date into 'July 2010' format
function getMonthYearString(dt) {
  return ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July',
          'August','September','October','November','December'][dt.getMonth()] +
         ' ' + dt.getFullYear();
}

// This is the function called when the user clicks any button
function chooseDate(e) {
  var targ; // Crossbrowser way to find the target (http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) targ = targ.parentNode; // defeat Safari bug

  var div = targ.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode; // Find the div
  var idOfTextbox = div.getAttribute('datepickertextbox'); // Get the textbox id which was saved in the div
  var textbox = document.getElementById(idOfTextbox); // Find the textbox now
  if (targ.value=='<' || targ.value=='>' || targ.value=='<<' || targ.value=='>>') { // Do they want the change the month?
    createCalendar(div, new Date(targ.getAttribute('date')));
    return;
  }
  textbox.value = targ.getAttribute('date'); // Set the selected date
  div.parentNode.removeChild(div); // Remove the dropdown box now
}

// Parse a date in d-MMM-yyyy format
function parseMyDate(d) {
  if (d=="") return new Date('NotADate'); // For Safari
  var a = d.split('-');
  if (a.length!=2) return new Date(d); // Missing 2 dashes
  var m = -1; // Now find the month
  if (a[1]=='01') m=0;
  if (a[1]=='02') m=1;
  if (a[1]=='03') m=2;
  if (a[1]=='04') m=3;
  if (a[1]=='05') m=4;
  if (a[1]=='06') m=5;
  if (a[1]=='07') m=6;
  if (a[1]=='08') m=7;
  if (a[1]=='09') m=8;
  if (a[1]=='10') m=9;
  if (a[1]=='11') m=10;
  if (a[1]=='12') m=11;
  if (m<0) return new Date(d); // Couldn't find the month
  var d = -1; // Now find the month
  if (a[1]=='01') d=0;
  if (a[1]=='02') d=1;
  if (a[1]=='03') d=2;
  if (a[1]=='04') d=3;
  if (a[1]=='05') d=4;
  if (a[1]=='06') d=5;
  if (a[1]=='07') d=6;
  if (a[1]=='08') d=7;
  if (a[1]=='09') d=8;
  if (a[1]=='10') d=9;
  if (a[1]=='11') d=10;
  if (a[1]=='12') d=11;
  if (a[1]=='13') d=12;
  if (a[1]=='14') d=13;
  if (a[1]=='15') d=14;
  if (a[1]=='16') d=15;
  if (a[1]=='17') d=16;
  if (a[1]=='18') d=17;
  if (a[1]=='19') d=18;
  if (a[1]=='20') d=19;
  if (a[1]=='21') d=20;
  if (a[1]=='22') d=21;
  if (a[1]=='23') d=22;
  if (a[1]=='24') d=23;
  if (a[1]=='25') d=24;
  if (a[1]=='26') d=25;
  if (a[1]=='27') d=26;
  if (a[1]=='28') d=27;
  if (a[1]=='29') d=28;
  if (a[1]=='30') d=29;
  if (a[1]=='31') d=30;
  if (d<0) return new Date(d); // Couldn't find the month
  return new Date(0,0,0,0,m,a[0],d,a[2]);
}

// This creates the calendar for a given month
function createCalendar(div, month) {
  var idOfTextbox = div.getAttribute('datepickertextbox'); // Get the textbox id which was saved in the div
  var textbox = document.getElementById(idOfTextbox); // Find the textbox now
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  var topRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);
  var td = topRow.insertCell(-1);
  var lastYearBn = document.createElement('input');
  lastYearBn.type='button'; // Have to immediately set the type due to IE
  td.appendChild(lastYearBn);
  lastYearBn.value='<<';
  lastYearBn.onclick=chooseDate;
  lastYearBn.setAttribute('date',new Date(month.getFullYear(),month.getMonth()-12,1,0,0,0,0).toString());
  var td = topRow.insertCell(-1);
  var lastMonthBn = document.createElement('input');
  lastMonthBn.type='button'; // Have to immediately set the type due to IE
  td.appendChild(lastMonthBn);
  lastMonthBn.value='<';
  lastMonthBn.onclick=chooseDate;
  lastMonthBn.setAttribute('date',new Date(month.getFullYear(),month.getMonth()-1,1,0,0,0,0).toString());
  var td = topRow.insertCell(-1);
  td.colSpan=3;
  var mon = document.createElement('input');
  mon.type='text';
  td.appendChild(mon);
  mon.value = getMonthYearString(month);
  mon.size=15;
  mon.disabled='disabled';
  mon.className='monthDsp';
  var td = topRow.insertCell(-1);
  var nextMonthBn = document.createElement('input');
  nextMonthBn.type='button';
  td.appendChild(nextMonthBn);
  nextMonthBn.value = '>';
  nextMonthBn.onclick=chooseDate;
  nextMonthBn.setAttribute('date',new Date(month.getFullYear(),month.getMonth()+1,1,0,0,0,0).toString());
  var td = topRow.insertCell(-1);
  var nextYearBn = document.createElement('input');
  nextYearBn.type='button'; // Have to immediately set the type due to IE
  td.appendChild(nextYearBn);
  nextYearBn.value='>>';
  nextYearBn.onclick=chooseDate;
  nextYearBn.setAttribute('date',new Date(month.getFullYear(),month.getMonth()+12,1,0,0,0,0).toString());  
  var daysRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Mon";  
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Tue";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Wed";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Thu";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Fri";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Sat";
  daysRow.insertCell(-1).innerHTML="Sun";
  daysRow.className='daysRow';  
  // Make the calendar
  var selected = parseMyDate(textbox.value); // Try parsing the date
  var today = new Date();
  date = new Date(month.getFullYear(),month.getMonth(),1,0,0,0,0); // Starting at the 1st of the month
  var extras = (date.getDay() + 6) % 7; // How many days of the last month do we need to include?
  date.setDate(date.getDate()-extras); // Skip back to the previous monday
  while (1) { // Loop for each week
    var tr = tbl.insertRow(-1);
    for (i=0;i<7;i++) { // Loop each day of this week
      var td = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var inp = document.createElement('input');
      inp.type = 'button';
      td.appendChild(inp);
      inp.value = date.getDate();
      inp.onclick = chooseDate;
      inp.setAttribute('date',getDateString(date));
      if (date.getMonth() != month.getMonth()) {
        if (inp.className) inp.className += ' ';
        inp.className+='othermonth';
      }
      if (date.getDate()==today.getDate() && date.getMonth()==today.getMonth() && date.getFullYear()==today.getFullYear()) {
        if (inp.className) inp.className += ' ';
        inp.className+='today';
      }
      if (!isNaN(selected) && date.getDate()==selected.getDate() && date.getMonth()==selected.getMonth() && date.getFullYear()==selected.getFullYear()) {
        if (inp.className) inp.className += ' ';
        inp.className+='selected';
      }
      date.setDate(date.getDate()+1); // Increment a day
    }
    // We are done if we've moved on to the next month
    if (date.getMonth() != month.getMonth()) {
      break;
    }
  }

  // At the end, we do a quick insert of the newly made table, hopefully to remove any chance of screen flicker
  if (div.hasChildNodes()) { // For flicking between months
    div.replaceChild(tbl, div.childNodes[0]);
  } else { // For creating the calendar when they first click the icon
    div.appendChild(tbl);
  }
}

// This is called when they click the icon next to the date inputbox
function showDatePicker(idOfTextbox) {
  var textbox = document.getElementById(idOfTextbox);

  // See if the date picker is already there, if so, remove it
  x = textbox.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    if (x[i].getAttribute('class')=='datepickerdropdown') {
      textbox.parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Grab the date, or use the current date if not valid
  var date = parseMyDate(textbox.value);
  if (isNaN(date)) date = new Date();

  // Create the box
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className='datepickerdropdown';
  div.setAttribute('datepickertextbox', idOfTextbox); // Remember the textbox id in the div
  createCalendar(div, date); // Create the calendar
  insertAfter(div, textbox); // Add the box to screen just after the textbox
  return false;
}

// Adds an item after an existing one
function insertAfter(newItem, existingItem) {
  if (existingItem.nextSibling) { // Find the next sibling, and add newItem before it
    existingItem.parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, existingItem.nextSibling); 
  } else { // In case the existingItem has no sibling after itself, append it
    existingItem.parentNode.appendChild(newItem);
  }
}


function onDOMReady(fn,ctx){var ready,timer;var onStateChange=function(e){if(e&&e.type=="DOMContentLoaded"){fireDOMReady()}else if(e&&e.type=="load"){fireDOMReady()}else if(document.readyState){if((/loaded|complete/).test(document.readyState)){fireDOMReady()}else if(!!document.documentElement.doScroll){try{ready||document.documentElement.doScroll('left')}catch(e){return}fireDOMReady()}}};var fireDOMReady=function(){if(!ready){ready=true;fn.call(ctx||window);if(document.removeEventListener)document.removeEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",onStateChange,false);document.onreadystatechange=null;window.onload=null;clearInterval(timer);timer=null}};if(document.addEventListener)document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",onStateChange,false);document.onreadystatechange=onStateChange;timer=setInterval(onStateChange,5);window.onload=onStateChange};

// This is called when the page loads, it searches for inputs where the class is 'datepicker'
onDOMReady(function(){
  // Search for elements by class
  var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) {
    var className = allElements[i].className;
    if (className=='datepicker' || className.indexOf('datepicker ') != -1 || className.indexOf(' datepicker') != -1) {
      // Found one! Now lets add a datepicker next to it  
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href='#';
      a.className="datepickershow";
      a.setAttribute('onclick','return showDatePicker("' + allElements[i].id + '")');
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src='data:image/png;base64,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';
      img.title='Show calendar';
      a.appendChild(img);
      insertAfter(a, allElements[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

[JavaScript Datepicker](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vq2vfpa9/2/)

So what am I doing wrong with the date, causing it to put the next day in when you click on the date? Example: User chooses 8/18/2016, but once click the date picker chooses 8/19/2016.

Comment: I copied your code and can reproduce the problem.  I removed the `$( "#format" ).change(function() {` handler stuff to simplify and it still shows the wrong date.   Where did that datepicker come from? Looks like a bug with it to me - or maybe a timezone config issue?  Have you considered jQuery UI Datepicker?

Comment: I have tried the  jQuery UI Datepicker in my custom wordpress template, but it didn't want to pull up the calendar when clicked on it, especially for some weird reason in FireFox.  Tried mulitple times for  jQuery UI Datepicker but doesn't want to seem to work in the custom wordpress template..

Comment: Is it possible to fix this code?